# Can an Uchiha remain powerful without embracing hatred?

Tags: naruto

Tobirama Senju stated that hatred births the Sharingan and strengthens it:

[image: Hatred and the Sharingan]

Can an Uchiha remain powerful without hatred? If not, does this imply that Itachi was full of hatred?

Comment: See - http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/317/how-should-we-handle-links-to-external-manga-readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itachi didn't seem like that hateful of a person, and he was very powerful.

Comment: That's the reason for the question.

Comment: @iOraelosi ah, well, than it seems as though you've answered your own question then.

Comment: I see... **facepalm**

Answer (score 3):

I don't think hatred is the only feeling that makes an Uchiha powerful, since many strong feelings (e.g. pain) can strengthen him, and this is just a quicker way to gain more power.
If an Uchiha sees their close friend or relative die, they gain Mangekyou Sharingan, but the feeling of hatred is not a necessity (Itachi hated no one when he saw Shisui commiting suicide).
So, I believe the feeling of hatred CAN make an Uchiha powerful, but it's not the power source. In short, a strong feeling is just a trigger, and once you awaken the Mangekyou Sahringan with it, you remain powerful.